# Fake X11 rendering as output to vector format

Tags: opengl, x11, vector-graphics

I'm provided with an application which renders highly complex geometries either via X11 or OpenGL (a computed voronoi diagram and other things).

I'm searching for a way to export renderings to a vector file. Because of the complexity of how the geometries are rendered, this does not seem to be as easy as thought.

I thought I could use Xfvb to fake parts of the rendering. But how can I later vectorize (or pseudo-vectorize) the screen buffer?

I do have a chance to change the screen to output only one kind at a time.

Or is there a way to substitute for example XFillArc() with something that, given a screen width and scale, provides for example a linestring?

Comment: Some of what you are asking reminds me of the old feedback buffer _(not to be confused with transform feedback)_ in OpenGL. You could put OpenGL into a special command mode, where it serializes rasterization commands into the "feedback buffer" that you can replay and other things. I am not sure if that is the sort of thing you're after, but if it is, modern GL will not help you (GL deprecated that in 3.0).

Comment: Intercept X11 requests. They *are* vector commands. That is, unless the application does the rasterization itself and only BLTs images to the X server. Use [a tool like xscope or similar](http://www.x.org/wiki/guide/debugging/).